# Docker error: Cannot start service ...: network 7808732465bd529e6f20e4071115218b2826f198f8cb10c3899de527c3b637e6 not found

Tags: docker, networking

When starting a docker container (not developed by me), docker says a network  has not been found.

Does this mean the problem is within the container itself (so only the developer can fix it), or is it possible to change some network configuration to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently VPN was causing this. Turning off VPN and resetting Docker to factory settings has solved the problem in two computers in our company. A third, personal computer that did not have VPN never showed the problem.

Answer (score 174):

I'm assuming you're using docker-compose and seeing this error. I'd recommend

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate <name>
```

That should recreate the containers as well as supporting services such as the network in question (it will likely create a new network).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed using docker-compose. Resetting Docker to factory settings worked... I will try your solution if it comes up again.

Comment: Super happy to help, it would be awesome if you'd accept the answer, that way other coming this way will have a clear signal that it worked :). More on accepting answers -> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: The thing is that I didn't try your solution, I reset to factory settings before seeing your answer... That's why I upvoted but didn't accept as an answer...

Comment: Oh gotcha, well it might make sense to describe what you did in a bit more detail and accept that :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was working on another project using docker-compose and had network issues.  I forgot that I had run `docker network prune` which, of course, trashed all my docker networks!

Comment: What would <name> be in this command? A container ID? Image ID? Something else?

Comment: I have a similar issue today, Once my host accidentally powered off immediatelly, the same error message came up when I try to start up the container. This answer brings my container up again. Thanks. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 118):

shutdown properly first, then restart

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

Comment: I did messed up with "docker network prune", so I had to do this clean solution to have my stack up again. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. I was bringing up the network via Docker Desktop's Dashboard. I brought things down via the command line and then up again and it works.

Answer (score 22):

This can be caused by some old service that has not been killed, first add
`--remove-orphans` flag when bringing down your container to remove any undead services running, then bring the container back up

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans

docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 15):

I was facing this similar issue and this worked for me :

Try running this 
`- docker container ls -a` and remove the container id by `docker container rm ca877071ac10` (this is the container id ).

The problem was there were some old container instances which were not removed. Once all the old terminated instances get removed, you can start the container with docker-compose file

Comment: tried with rm didn't work, properly shutting down the docker-compose or force recreate helps

Answer (score 10):

This is based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571715/6322179).

In my case the steps that produced the error where:

1. Server restart, containers from a docker-compose stack remained stopped.
2. Network prune ran, so the network associated with stack containers where deleted.
3. Running `docker-compose --project-name "my-project" up -d` failed with the error described in this topic.

Solved simply adding force-recreate, in this way:

```
docker-compose --project-name "my-project" up -d --force-recreate
```

This possibly works because with this containers are recreated linked with the also recreated network (previously pruned as described in the pre conditions).

Comment: first run... docker-compose down and after docker-compose up -d --force-recreate

Answer (score 5):

Amongst other things `docker system prune` will remove 'all networks not used by at least one container' allowing them to be recreated next docker-compose up

More precisely `docker network prune` can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Find the name of the network in the NetworkSettings/Networks section

```
docker inspect container_name
```

Create a new network

```
docker network create network_name
```

Connect the network to the container

```
docker network connect network_name container_name
```